# Get value from custom setting

Tags: apex, apex-variable

I have a batch process that I want to be able to dynamically tweak the batch size without changing the code in sandbox and then deploying each time. I figure I can use a custom setting as I have been bringing that logic to enable/disable some of our new functionality.

I have written this snipit:

```
// Number of opportunity items that can be handled within a single execution context taken from custom setting
Revenue_Pipeline_Settings__c setting = Revenue_Pipeline_Settings__c.getInstance();
Integer oppsize = setting.Batch_Size__c;

private static final Integer MAX_OPPTLI_IN_BATCH = oppsize;
```

I keep getting the error

> Variable does not exist: oppsize

This is no matter what I put after the equals sign.

Is there a way to reference the custom setting number field without error?

EDIT Final Solution used both answers:

```
static Revenue_Pipeline_Settings__c setting = Revenue_Pipeline_Settings__c.getInstance();
static Integer oppsize = Integer.valueOf(setting.Batch_Size__c);

private static final Integer MAX_OPPTLI_IN_BATCH = oppsize;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change Integer `oppsize` to static as that is being accessed from static variable.

```
static Integer oppsize = setting.Batch_Size__c;

private static final Integer MAX_OPPTLI_IN_BATCH = oppsize;
```

Comment: If I go this route then it says variable does not exist setting.batch size. Do you put static in front of this?

Revenue_Pipeline_Settings__c setting = Revenue_Pipeline_Settings__c.getInstance();

Comment: whenever you try to access any static variable both of them must be static

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use type casting here like :
`Integer oppsize = Integer.valueOf(setting.Batch_Size__c);`.
By default it returns value in decimal so we need to change it to integer.

Comment: If I follow this it still gives the error variable does not exist.